# How to match strings with at most n free characters between two well-defined patterns?

Tags: regex, grep

Let's say I have the text from a bunch of articles. I want to be be able to grep for patterns related to COVID-19. How would I search for such a thing considering that some people call it Cov2, CoV-2, COVID-2, COVID19, COVID-19, COVID 19, etc...

Basically, that pattern I have so far is

```
grep "[Cc][Oo][Vv].{0,3}2\|[Cc][Oo][Vv].{0,3]19" file.txt
```

But this isn't working. I'm pretty sure the problem is the ".{0,3}" part. I'm not sure how to tell the computer to match *up to 3 free characters*, followed by 2 or 19, and preceded by [Cc][Oo][Vv]

Comment: `grep -i -E "COV.{0,3}(2|19)"`?

Comment: fyi, your regex works if you escape the `{` and `}` symbols (using the flag `-E` means you no longer need to escape those characters)

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you have a GNU `grep`, your pattern contains several mistakes:

- `{0,3}` - in a POSIX BRE pattern, a range quantifier is defined with a pair of *escaped* braces, `\{0,3\}`
- `{0,3]` - same comment, just the closing braces got replaced with `]`.

You can use

```
grep -i -E "COV.{0,3}(2|19)" file
```

Or, a bit more precise:

```
grep -i -E "COV(ID)?[-[:space:]]?(2|19)"
```

See [an online `grep` demo #1](https://ideone.com/qZfpVr) and a [demo #2](https://ideone.com/waS9gv).

**Details**

- `-i` - case insensitive mode
- `-E` - POSIX ERE syntax enabled (to avoid extra `\` symbols in the regex pattern)
- `COV.{0,3}(2|19)` - `COV` substring (case insensitive), then any zero to three chars, and then either `2` or `19`
- `(ID)?[-[:space:]]?` - matches an optional `ID` substring, and then an optional `-` or a whitespace char.

Comment: Thank you. I'm wondering why my pattern didn't work though. It seems like it should've been able to capture that pattern

Comment: @ZuhaibAhmed Please check the updated answer, I added the explanation.